# Is a grow light sufficient for an indoor olive tree over the winter?

Tags: grow-lamp, olive

I have two small olive trees which I would like to grow indoors. Olive trees need a lot of light. Winter is coming and it will be fairly dark here, especially indoors. Will an ordinary grow light be sufficient to keep the olive tree healthy over the winter?